# Is it possible to create an interceptor for any redirection in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, interceptor

I'm creating a tool to detect redirections and show them in an admin panel.

I want to somehow know about all redirections without the developer getting involved.

Is it possible in ASP.NET Core?

If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "interceptor"?

Comment: @Dai, the interceptor pattern. Something that exists in Axios or EF Core. To augment functionality without writing it everywhere. I know about middleware in ASP.NET Core. But I'm not sure if they can be used for that purpose.

Comment: your means is visitor come from where? or visitors going where after your site? (both can be implement)

Comment: @foadabdollahi, I want to add a DLL to a project, configure it in one line preferably, and then log any redirect call. `Response.Redirect` for example.

Answer (score 1):

This problem must require developer intervention, which can be stored in logs. Convenient to display records in your admin panel.

```
public class RedirectHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<RedirectHandlerMiddlerware> _logger;

    public RedirectHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<RedirectHandlerMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await HandleRedirect(context, ex);
        await _next(context);
    }

    private Task HandleRedirect(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 302)
        {
            ...
            //context.Response.Redirect("...");
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

You need to register in Startup.cs. It should be placed after `app.UseAuthentication();`.

```
app.UseMiddleware<RedirectHandlingMiddleware>();
```